# Android NDK - The runtime doesn't get packaged to the APK

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I set up in my Application.mk
APP_STL := gnustl_shared

To use the gnustl_shared,
From my understanding it should pack the libgnustl_shared.so in my apk file under:
apk/lib//libgnustl_shared.so

But all I am seeing there is my .so file.

Also verified it by trying to load the library:

```
try {
    System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Native library failed to load: " + e);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

But the load failed.

Any1 knows how can I make the Android ndk build package the Android runtime aswell?

Answer (score -1):

When you make the apk, it doesn't package the libgnustl_shared.so. It just tells the linker to link against that library. You also should not try to load that library as it is loaded by the system when your application is started. That, unless you target androids that are prior to Android API level 18. Then, you should use the shared library variant  and you must load the shared library before any other library that depends on it. I assume that if you put the min-version for the NDK, it will work...

Comment: Also, STL is a runtime support library. It provides some runtime calls like assert. You can just call those functions and they should work, no need to package or load it...